# Populating dropdown using ajax php codeigniter

Tags: php, json, ajax, codeigniter, dropdown

I have been trying all the help available on different forums but now give up and posting my question here. Trying to populate dropdown using ajax call. Getting the data in json format successfully. But don't know to fill dropdown. code below:
Controller:

```
function getRegion()
{
    $this->load->model('Settings_model');
    $title = $this->input->get('title');

    $result =   array("region" => $this->Settings_model->getSelectedRegion($title));
    echo json_encode($result);      
}
```

View:

```
        $(document).on('change', '#campaignSel', function() {
        changecampaign();
    });

    function changecampaign(){
        var title= "New Normal";//$('#campaignSel option:selected').text();//$('#campaignSel').text();
        $regionSel = $("#regionSel");
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url: "<?php echo base_url('Pricecomparison/getRegion'); ?>",
                data:{ "title":"New Normal"},
                datatype: "json",
                success: function(result){
                    var appenddata;
                    $.each(result, function (key, value) {
                        appenddata += "<option value = '" + value.id + " '>" + value.region + " </option>";                        
                    });
                    $('#regionSel').html(appenddata);
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
                    console.log(xhr.statusText);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        }
```

Response: {"region":[{"id":"1","region":"109 FEATHERSTON ST (ELEC)\r\n"},{"id":"2","region":"ASHBURTON/MID CANTERBURY
 ELEC"}]}
I want to fill dropdown with Regions.

Comment: $.each(result.region, function (key, value) {
                        appenddata += "<option value = '" + value.id + " '>" + value.region + " </option>";                        
                    });

Comment: gives this error  TypeError: obj is undefined
 length = obj.length,

Comment: may be your response data is empty

Comment: try my updated answer @Danish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved the issues in my code. I like to share the changes I made to my code below:
added:

```
contentType: "application/json",
```

and

```
parsedobj = JSON.parse(result)
```

so the final ajax code is:

```
$.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url: "<?php echo base_url('Pricecomparison/getRegion'); ?>",
                data:{ "title":title},
                contentType: "application/json",
                datatype: "json",
                success: function(result){
                     parsedobj = JSON.parse(result)
                     var appenddata='';
                        $.each(parsedobj.region, function(index, value) 
                        {
                            appenddata += "<option value = '" + index + "'>" + value.region + " </option>";    
                        });

                        $('#regionSel').html(appenddata); 
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
                    console.log(xhr.statusText);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to loop the region like this `$.each(result.region, function (key, value) {`   instead of result

**Update1:**

added if condition `if ($.isArray(result.region)){ ... }`

```js
result =  {"region":[{"id":"1","region":"109 FEATHERSTON ST (ELEC)\r\n"},{"id":"2","region":"ASHBURTON/MID CANTERBURY ELEC"}]}
var appenddata='';
if ($.isArray(result.region)){
$.each(result.region, function (key, value) {
                        appenddata += "<option value = '" + value.id + " '>" + value.region + " </option>";    
                        
                        console.log(appenddata);
                    });
                    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have been trying the same for years. but it does not populate the dropdown. and give this error too.     TypeError: obj is undefined

length = obj.length,

Comment: if condition helps in not to thru the error. But the question is that how come the response data is empty since it display the data in console. console.log(result); Means data is coming in response.